# Error when pulling from git in ansible - {Failed to find required executable git}

Tags: git, github, ansible

I am trying to pull from two of my Git repos using Ansible but I seem to be getting this error:

```
failed: [app01] (item={u'dest': u'/etc/', u'repo': u'Vigorate'}) =>{"failed": true, "item": {"dest": "/etc/", "repo": "Vigorate"}, "msg": "Failed to find required executable git"}
failed: [app01] (item={u'dest': u'/etc/', u'repo': u'Paint-UI'}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"dest": "/etc/", "repo": "Paint-UI"}, "msg": "Failed to find required executable git"}
```

My git.yml playbook looks like this:

EDIT:

```
- hosts: app01
vars:
 - destination: /home/vagrant/rep
tasks:

- name: Install dependencies
  apt: name={{ item }} state=present
  with_items:
    - htop
    - git-all

- name: Pull from Git
  git: repo=http://git@github.com/*****/{{ item.repo }}.git
       dest={{ item.dest }}
      # accept_hostkey=yes
      # force=yes
      # recursive=no
  with_items:
    -
      dest: "{{ destination }}"
      repo: RepoEexample
  #  -
   #   dest: "{{ destination }}"
    #  repo: RepoExample
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

I believe this error suggests that the `git:` in your ansible playbook is unrecognized and doesn't exist. You want to make sure that you've installed git before using it. Something like:

```
 - name: Install dependencies
   yum: name={{ item }} state=present
   with_items:
     - htop
     - git-all
     - python-devel
```

would install htop, git, and python so then you run your `git` stanza.

If you're sure git is installed, then the next possible error might be the syntax of your `with_items` section. Try breaking it up into two different stanzas of code (tedious, yes) just to make sure it works and if it does, it's the formatting of current version and not a git problem.

----------UPDATE

Make sure the below works and then focus on having multiple repos cloned with the single stanza of code.

```
- name: Pull from Git
  git: repo=git@github.com/daniyalj/Vigorate.git
       dest=/path/to/destination
```

Comment: Okay that solved it!

But now I seem to be getting the error "fatal: repository 'git@github.com/daniyalj/Vigorate.git' does not exist\n"

Thanks for your your help @laughing-horse

Comment: Wonderful! 
You're going to want to double check the git-URL there. make sure you have the right one (whether it's http or ssh). Again, I recommend writing the code without the variables to make sure you have nailed down the syntax before getting fancy and then throw those back in.

Comment: You're welcome (I'd appreciate the upvote!). Goodluck working with the rest of your ansible work (just finished the a month of ansible configurations myself :) )